# How to keep console window open

Tags: c#, console-application

When I run my program, the console window seems to run and close.  How to keep it open so I can see the results?

```
class Program
{
    public class StringAddString       
    {                        
        public virtual void AddString()
        {
            var strings2 = new string[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5","6", "7", "8", "9"};

            Console.WriteLine(strings2);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {          
        StringAddString s = new StringAddString();            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You forgot calling your method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{          
    StringAddString s = new StringAddString();  
    s.AddString();
}
```

it should stop your console, but the result might not be what you expected, you should change your code a little bit:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", strings2));
```

Answer (score 106):

Put a Console.Read() as the last line in your program. That will prevent it from closing until you press a key

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    StringAddString s = new StringAddString();
    Console.Read();            
}
```

Comment: @user1929393 AS TGH pointed out, put it under you `static void Main`. This is the starting point of the execution.

Comment: `Console.Read()` waits for 'Enter' key. I'm using `Console.ReadKey()` for "Press any key to continue..."

Answer (score 38):

If you want to keep the console open when you are debugging, but still let it close normally when not debugging, you can do something like this:

```cs
if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) Console.ReadLine();
```

As other answers have stated, the call to `Console.ReadLine()` will keep the window open until <kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed. With the above code, `Console.ReadLine()` will only be called if the debugger is attached.

Answer (score 22):

There are two ways that I know of.

1. Put `Console.ReadLine()` at the end of your program. Disadvantage: you have to change your code, and have to remember to remove it later on.
2. Run without a debugger, using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>. This opens a console window outside of Visual Studio, and that window won't close when finished. Advantage: you don't have to change your code. Disadvantage: if there is an exception, the program won't drop into the debugger. (However, when you do get exceptions, you can simply rerun with a debugger.)

Answer (score 19):

```cs
Console.ReadKey(true);
```

This command is a bit nicer than `ReadLine`, which passes only when you hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. The `true` parameter here hides the ugly flashing cursor while reading the result. Any keystroke terminates the program.

Answer (score 12):

You can handle this without requiring a user input.

Step 1. Create a ManualRestEvent at the start of Main thread

```
ManualResetEvent manualResetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
```

Step 2 . Wait ManualResetEvent

```
manualResetEvent.WaitOne();
```

Step 3.To Stop

```
manualResetEvent.Set();
```

Answer (score 6):

Write `Console.ReadKey();` in the last line of `main()` method. This line prevents finishing the console. I hope it would help you.

Answer (score 6):

If your using Visual Studio just run the application with Crtl + F5 instead of F5. This will leave the console open when it's finished executing.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Visual Studio, then the IDE has an option to keep the window open under

> Tools > Options > Debugging >
>
> Automatically close the console when debugging stops

Unlike <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>, this allows you to use breakpoints while debugging.

Comment: I prefer this answer because it's configuring the tools correctly, rather than making unnecessary changes to the code.

Answer (score 2):

Use Console.Readline() at the end .Your code will not close until you close it manually.Since Readline waits for input that needs to be entered for your code hence your console will be open until you type some input.

Answer (score 2):

For visual c# console Application use:

```
Console.ReadLine();
Console.Read();
Console.ReadKey(true);
```

for visual c++ win32 console application use:

```
system("pause");
```

press ctrl+f5 to run the application.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to use`Console.ReadLine();`
to keep the preceeding `Console.WriteLine("");` message from closing.

Answer (score 1):

Console.Read()

-> Console stays open until you press a button on your keyboard

Answer (score 0):

To be able to give it input without it closing as well you could enclose the code in a while loop

```
while (true) 
{
     <INSERT CODE HERE>
}
```

It will continue to halt at `Console.ReadLine();`, then do another loop when you input something.