How do I keep the console window open after running a C# program?
Problem Statement:
I'm learning C# and created a simple console application that prints 'Hello World'. However, the console window closes immediately after running the program, and I can't see the output. What is the best way to keep the console window open so I can view the output after running my C# program?
I've researched online and found suggestions to add Console.ReadLine(); at the end of the Main method to keep the console window open until I press Enter. This workaround does work, and I can see the 'Hello World' message, but I'm unsure if this is the best practice or if there are better ways to handle this situation in C#.

this is really a duplicate question to this (my preferred answer) - https://stackoverflow.com/a/16953021/6908545

Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit..."); Console.ReadKey(); ? Or stop using .NET Framework and switch to a more modern version of .NET (e.g. .NET 8) since the debugger in Visual Studio for .NET now incorporates this functionality.
